# Does Boost C++ library support Solaris on Sparc?

Tags: c++, boost, solaris, sparc

I have been looking at Boost libraries for development of a cross-platform network server library. It is supposed to be used on Windows/Linux/Solaris. Does boost support these three?

Only thing i can find by googling is some build trouble and that "Boost supports most modern operating systems"

I'm pretty new to Boost so maybe someone more used to it knows where this is more specifically specified?

Comment: In all boost releases there are versions, that this release support. Look here for example http://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_52_0.html

Comment: okay, thanks =) I see SunOS 5.10 is supported in Boost 1.52, which would mean Solaris 10 i assume. Thanks a lot @ForEveR :)

Comment: Okay, meta-question here: the comment is answer enough for me, can I mark it as answer so @ForEveR gets creds?

Comment: @ForEveR can post his comment as an answer, then you can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In all boost releases there are versions, that this release support. Look for example [here](http://boost.org/users/history/version_1_52_0.html)